# underscorejs _uniq not filtering correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, underscore.js

I'm using underscorejs with my angular project in order to get remove duplicate objects in my array. 
Underscorejs is filtering, but for some reason it's only keeping two string arrays at a time in biddingGroup. If someone else makes a bid that isn't in the array, then it overwrites one of the array slots instead of appending the new row since it isn't unique. I appreciate any help with this!

Let me know if you need any more information.

```
var newBidder = [{
  bidderId: this.userId
}]

biddingGroup.push(newBidder);
console.log("BEFORE USING UNDERSCOREJS");
console.log(biddingGroup);

this.uniqueResult = _.uniq(biddingGroup, "bidderId");

console.log("UNIQUE RESULT");
console.log(this.uniqueResult);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your console output your initial array is not an array of objects but rather an array of one-element arrays of objects:

```
var biddingGroup = [
    [ { bidderId: xxx } ],
    [ { bidderId: xxx } ]
];
```

So the result is fine: The second array is removed as a duplicate of the first one (both have an undefined `bidderId`).